# How to run specific views on Xcode simulator?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, ios-simulator

My project can only run on devices and not simulator, it's an object-recognition app, is it possible to run a single view of my project that doesn't use any technology and is able to run on simulator? I need to do tests and I'd like not to run the app on the device every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new target for your project. then only add specific views and relevant source file to the current new target. remember to change the active scheme before run.

Comment: When adding a new target, should i select "App" as a template?

Comment: @jooh Yes. Select "App". I don't visit this site often. If you encounter some issues, you can contact me with twitter(Bai_Gang_zh)

Answer (score 1):

To run a specific view on the Xcode simulator, you can use the "Debug View Hierarchy" button in the simulator's "Debug" menu.

Comment: I clicked on "Debug view hierarchy" on the bottom bar of Xcode and it shows me: "Unable to capture view hierarchy"